# How create node with unicode property in Neo4jClient?

Tags: unicode, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am using Neo4jClient in `C#`.

I added several nodes with properties which contains string in `nicode` format. The thing is that when i query nodes back in `C#` i get `????` instead of `unicode` values the same happen when i review data via Neo4j server `DataBrowser` page.

I added node directly in `Neo4j server` with `unicode` property, everything looks ok.

How can i tune `Neo4jClient` to create node/relationships with `unicode` properties?

thank you in advance

p.s. in  `neo4j-wrapper.conf` file i found  `wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: Do you have an example of a property you are storing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue:

https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/25/unicode-characters-are-not-roundtripped

Please monitor that issue to know when it is fixed.